# "As a mean(s?) for"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What's more correct, the plural or singular use of "mean" in the following phrases:

- As a means for
- As a mean for

My intuition is the singular, the second one, since we have a singular "a" there. But common usage seems to be in the plural.

Answer (score 5):

The word "means" is, in this context, considered to be a singular noun. That is, both the singular and plural of this noun are written as "means". Just because a word ends in "s" doesn't mean it's a plural noun: take "lens", or "news" for example. See http://www.focus.olsztyn.pl/en-grammar-nouns-uncountable-s.html

Comment: I don't think *news* is a fitting example. It's a mass noun, so we talk about "an item of news", not "a news".

Comment: @ThePhoton That's news to me. Mass nouns, unless you're denying any concept of number at all, are generally considered to be singular. Your use of *a* to denote something singular is misleading. *The* is also used with singular items. I heard that on the news.

Comment: *The* is used with mass nouns all the time: The sand is hot. The water is wet. But we don't (without changing to a count noun usage like "I'll have a water, please") use *a* with mass nouns.

Comment: a species, comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

My sense would be the 1st one: *As a means for (to)*

The close idiom:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/means+to+an+end)

as **a means to an end**

> a thing that is not valued or important in itself but is useful in
>   achieving an aim.

End and means are compared or contrasted in several proverbial sayings, for example the end justifies the means (see end) and he who wills the end wills the means .